# ServiceNotFoundError: Service "Request" was not found,looks like it was not registered in the container

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I am new to typescript. I am receiving this error on the execution of the graphql .But this error appears in the code frequently.This error originated in typedi npm but i am not able to find the root cause as I am nowhere using "Request" Service.

ServiceNotFoundError: Service "Request" was not found, looks like it was not registered in the container. Register it by calling Container.set before using service.
    at new ServiceNotFoundError (/home/vvdn/LECBackend2/LECBackend/node_modules/typedi/error/ServiceNotFoundError.js:20:28)

```
at ContainerInstance.getServiceValue (/home/vvdn/LECBackend2/LECBackend/node_modules/typedi/ContainerInstance.js:149:19)

at ContainerInstance.get (/home/vvdn/LECBackend2/LECBackend/node_modules/typedi/ContainerInstance.js:51:21)

at resolvers.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) (/home/vvdn/LECBackend2/LECBackend/node_modules/vesper/SchemaBuilder.js:393:52)

at /home/vvdn/LECBackend2/LECBackend/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/schemaGenerator.js:518:26

at resolveFieldValueOrError (/home/vvdn/LECBackend2/LECBackend/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:531:18)

at resolveField (/home/vvdn/LECBackend2/LECBackend/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:495:16)

at /home/vvdn/LECBackend2/LECBackend/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:364:18
```

Comment: Looks like this error is specific to Vesper, and not GraphQL itself. It might be good to update your question to reflect that. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like we have a `vesper` tag to use :(

Comment: Make sure that the `constructor` in the `Request` service class is not private.